# Exploration Constant in UCB1 algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I'm currently writing a UCB1 algorithm for a game.  The algorithm as I'm using it is:

```
average(i) + sqrt( (2 * ln(totalcount)) / count(i) )
```

Where **averagei** is the average score of arm i, **count(i)** is the count for arm i, and **totalcount** is the total samples of all arms.  This is the equation for the score for a given arm i.  The arm with the highest score, max(i), is chosen to be sampled.  The algorithm then repeats this equation with the new data it got from that sample, ad infinitum, or until it runs out of thinking time.

I have an assignment which tells me to *"modify the exploration constant"* for the algorithm.  I also notice that it exploits rather than explores almost all the time -- it hardly ever tries arms it has only visited once.  However, I don't see any exploration constant.  Am I missing some part of the algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

The 2 is the exploration constant. The larger it is, the more the algorithm favors exploration over exploitation.

Also beware that this formula makes sense only when the payoffs are in [0,1] range, otherwise a large payoff (say 1000) will nullify the influence of the "exploration" part of the formula, effectively making it exploitation-only.